# How can I ensure a cookie can be read from a new window in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using javascript and trying to pass a sessionGUID via a cookie to a newly opened window using IE9. I wish to avoid putting the sessionGUID on the querystring.

I am using the following code to open the new window and assign the cookie to the new window:

```
var pathname = /msgViewer.htm?A=" + aGUID + "&Detached=yes"; 
var myWindow = window.open(pathname, "detached_window");
myWindow.document.cookie = "SG=" + sGUID;
```

However, the cookie doesn't appear to be set when (document).ready executes in the new window.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
...
sGUID = getCookie("SG");
...
[call to AJAX webservice that requires sGUID be passed]

...

    function getCookie(name) {
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    if (begin == -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0) return null;
    }
    else {
        begin += 2;
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) {
            end = dc.length;
        }
    }
    return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}
```

When I set a (test) alert after the getCookie call the sGUID is undefined, however the delay (user entry) caused by the alert allows the cookie to be read after that.

How can I ensure the cookie is set in the new window before $(document).ready executes?  ...or at least ensure the webservice isn't called before the sessionGUID is retrieved from the cookie?

The issue doesn't exist in FireFox or Chrome- just IE.

Thanks in advance, for your consideration...

UPDATE (20121115):
This link http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/220241/ indicates cookie data may not be available until after a page request has been made. The scenario described above generally only occurs during the initial login or after cookies have been deleted (and still intermittent at that) My current solution/workaround is to open and close a temp window and re-retrieve the cookie.  Since the issue happens when a new window is opening anyway, the additional window flicker is inconspicuous.  I also moved the retrieval of the cookie outside the $(document).ready function.
Here is the additional code:

```
sGUID = getCookie("SG");
if (sGUID == null) {
    var jwURL = "/Test.htm";
    jw = window.open(jwURL, "junk_window",width=1,height=1);
    jw.close();
    sGUID = getCookie("SG");
}
```

Comment: I've got a similar issue with IE.  We open a new window, and then set some properties on the window object returned by window.open().  In IE, those properties are not available on $(document).ready(), but after an alert they are.  Unfortunately our solution up to this point has been to set at timeout (100ms) and check then. I'm not happy with the solution, and I'm still trying to come up with a better solution, but it seems to work for now.

Comment: Why do you need to set the cookie on the new window?  Cookies are site specific not page specific.

Comment: Is this for some kind of oAuth or Central authentication?

Comment: Waxen: I've tried using setTimeout (of 1 ms to 2 seconds) in order to allow the cookie to populate but that didn't change the functionality.  Your post did make me realize that perhaps I need to move where I read the cookie out of the $(document).ready.  That didn't change the function either.  Where did you your set your delay?

Comment: nickles: For some reason the new window doesn't see the cookie (from the calling window or in the new window) until after I use an alert or get an error generated by my webservice.  In FireFox the cookie is available- but not IE. ... or at least how it is functioning for me... Shouldn't the cookie be accessible by the time the (document).ready function executes?

Comment: Worthycaesar: we are not using oAuth or Central Authentication.  The calling application (window) handles the user authentication and retrieves the session GUID.  When are trying to pass that GUID to the new window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Update 20121115" (opening/closing a temp window) did fix my issue.  I did ultimately use a different getCookie function to retrieve the cookie- however that doesn't directly relate to my initial question:

```
   function getCookie(c_name) {
        var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
        for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
            x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
            y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
            x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
            if (x == c_name) {
                return unescape(y);
            }
        }
    }
```